# Getting the closest date to a given date in BigQuery with no subqueries

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery

Trying to get back to the currency conversion rate at the moment the purchase happened, so the revenue calculation is exact.
BigQuery doesn't support subqueries, so doing something like these 2 queries won't work (they do work on the DB):

**Query 1**

```
SELECT
  b.id,
  j.id,
  j.currency,
  j.created,
  j.status,
  j.pricev,
  j.price,
  (
    select 
      erc.rfbcurr 
    from 
      test.exchangerates_exchangeratechange erc 
    join 
      test.exchangerates_exchangerate er on er.id = erc.exchangerateid
    where 
      erc.created < j.created and er.currencycode = j.currency 
    order by 
      erc.created desc
    limit 1
  ) as exchangerate
FROM 
  transferz-st.test.bs_b b
JOIN 
  transferz-st.test.bs_j j on j.bid = b.id;
```

**Query 2**

```
 SELECT
  b.id,
  j.id,
  j.currency,
  j.created,
  j.status,
  j.pricev,
  j.price,
  j.currency,
  erc.rfbcurr
FROM
  b
JOIN
  j on j.bid = b.id
JOIN
  exchangerate er on er.currencycode = j.currency
JOIN
  exchangeratechange erc on erc.exchangerateid = er.id
GROUP BY
  b.id,
  j.id,
  j.currency,
  j.created,
  j.status,
  j.pricevat,
  j.price,
  j.currency,
  erc.rfbcurr,
  erc.id
HAVING
    erc.id = (select erc2.id from exchangeratechange erc2 join exchangerate er2 on er2.id = rc2.id where erc2.created < j.created and er2.currencycode = j.currency order by erc2.created desc limit 1);
```

Could anybody suggest a solution?

Comment: BigQuery support [subqueries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/subqueries). can you provide what error you are getting.

Comment: Hi @Chandra. Thanks for your reply. Here it is:

Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a `JOIN` to bring in the currency rates.  Use `LEAD()` to get a date range:

```
WITH er AS (
      select erc.rfbcurr, er.currencycode, er.created, 
             lead(er.created) over (partition by er.currencycode order by er.created) as next_created
      from  test.exchangerates_exchangeratechange erc join 
            test.exchangerates_exchangerate er
            on er.id = erc.exchangerateid
     )
SELECT . . ., er.rfbcurr as exchange_rage
FROM transferz-st.test.bs_b b JOIN 
     transferz-st.test.bs_j j 
     ON j.bid = b.id JOIN
     er
     ON er.currencycode = j.currency AND
        j.created >= er.created AND
        (er.next_created IS NULL OR j.created < er.next_created);
```